# Why are there two rake gemspecs in an rvm installation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rvm

Why are there two rake gemspecs in an rvm installation?

```
~ - 10:59>find ~/.rvm/ -name 'rake-0.8.7.gemspec'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec  # alias
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec
```

Why are they different? (The non-gem version only contains the name and version).

Why doesn't the gem command always use the spec in the .rvm/gems dir, and how do I convince it to do so?

(This is a piece of the puzzle in order to solve [this problem with installing ffi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127949/136).

Comment: This question hasn't got a correct answer yet, and I'm still interested in one.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the RVM concept of gemsets. It allows you have different groups of gem installs that you can make active.

Read more about gemsets here:

- https://rvm.io/gemsets/